# jquery ajax Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : while calling an api

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get a json response from the comicvine api but am getting the following error. comicvine.gamespot.com/:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

I see my json result, formatted, in the response body but am getting the console error above.

```
export function getSeriesFromComicVine() {
  const url = "http://comicvine.gamespot.com/api/characters/?api_key=f18c6362ec6d4c0d7b6d550f36478c1cd6c04a49&filter=gender:male,name:hawkeye&format=json&callback=?";
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    // data: {test: "test"},
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: false,
    jsonpCallback: "myJsonMethod"
    success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
     }
  });
}
```

Comment: `I see my json result, formatted` - but is it valid (computer says no), `in the response header` - surely it's in the response **body**!

Comment: can you see that the response is indeed JSON - but not JSONP - looks like `comicvine.gamespot.com` doesn't do JSONP

Comment: Well I am getting the response. And all of the examples that I have seen have used jsonp. I will add the response I am getting in the question.

Comment: well, you must be doing something wrong, because the response is JSON, not JSONP

Comment: Yes. I assumed I was doing something wrong. Any idea of what though? When I have regular json as my datatype, I get the cross origin error.

Comment: yes, ... your sending `format=json` instead of `format=jsonp` - and your not naming the jsonp callback parameter correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `format=jsonp` not `json`

the jsonp callback parameter name needs to be `json_callback` according to `comicvine.gamespot.com` - I found this out by going to url `https://comicvine.gamespot.com/api/characters/?api_key=[your api key]&filter=gender:male,name:hawkeye&format=jsonp` in the browser, and it told me what was missing - very friendly API - the response had an error value

```
"'jsonp' format requires a 'json_callback' argument"
```

and no need for `callback=?` in the url - seeing as jquery adds the callback parameter and it isn't named callback

```
function getSeriesFromComicVine() {
    const url = "https://comicvine.gamespot.com/api/characters/?api_key=[your api key]&filter=gender:male,name:hawkeye&format=jsonp";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: "json_callback",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```